# (Captivate) Hide object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adobe-captivate

I am trying to hide and show objects inside Captivate using Captivate JavaScript window, but even though it feels like it should be very easy to do, I cannot get my objects to show!

So far I've tried the following:

```
var slideNum = window.cpAPIInterface.getCurrentSlideIndex();   // to get current slide number

var CC = $("#CC_text_" + slideNum);      // to get a proper object name as I have similar objects on every page
```

after that I tried standard JS approaches like CC.hide(); tried changing visibility, etc, but nothing works.  Has anyone tried anything like this before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue just today as luck would have it. The issue is that `$("#CC_text_" + slideNum);` returns the *accessibility* object that is on top of you the object you want. The actual object is a canvas element underneath the accessibility object, and conveniently has the same id + "c". So you'll want:

```
$("#CC_text_" + slideNum + "c");
```

Additionally, it appears that objects that are hidden from output (failure captions etc) are set to `display: block; visibility: hidden;` so `.show()` won't work, you'll need to use `.css('visibility', 'visible')`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://helpx.adobe.com/captivate/using/common-js-interface.html

It clearly says:

To hide any object, use cp.hide("object_name");

To show any object, use cp.show("object_name");

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "starts with" option of JQuery:

```
 $(['id^="CC_text_"']);
```

Answer (score -1):

To show/hide any object via javascript that is contained in the project (i.e., you've entered it via the actions window), I always use:

```
cp.hide('myText'); // obviously substitute show with hide function
```

Answer (score -1):

Just found this. Objects on a master slide e.g. navigation can be accessed with cp.show("objectname"); / cp.hide("objectname"); though I have seen some weird behaviour with the play bar buttons (they will hide but not show once hidden).